# A "concatenation-like" cryptographic operation that has a fixed output?

Tags: hash, compression-function

I am designing a cryptographic protocol, and I was wondering whether or not there exists a simple cryptographic operation $\diamond$ that is:

- Associative: $(x\diamond y)\diamond z = x \diamond(y\diamond z)$
- Non-commutative: $x\neq y \Rightarrow x\diamond y \neq y \diamond x$
- Collision-resistant: it's hard to find two different pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ such that $x \diamond y = x' \diamond y'$.

The obvious operation that fits these properties is concatentation with some sort of unique separator, and that's indeed what I'm currently using in my protocol.

But is there such an "append-like" binary operation that produces a fixed-size result? Append-and-hash wouldn't work since it is not associative: $H(H(x||y)||z)\neq H(x||H(y||z))$. XOR won't work since it's neither unique nor non-commutative. Ideally such an operation would be a simple construction using a hash function or other "standard" crypto primitive.

Comment: What is the goal here? An obvious example would be something like x⋄y = E(x)||E(y) for some permutation E.

Comment: Uniqueness is not possible if you allow inputs longer than the fixed-size result. Is collision-resistance (i.e. colliding pairs are hard to find) sufficient?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, collision-resistance is sufficient.

Comment: @TjadenHess The context in the protocol is essentially computing a hash $H(x_1||x_2||\dots||x_n)$ with each party contributing some arbitrary nonoverlapping range $x_i,\dots,x_j$. So associativity and non-commutativeness are essential, but replacing concatenation with a fixed-output $\diamond$ in the protocol will save space.